# next.js export static - S3 - routing fails on page reload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

I'm deploying a next.js app as a static export, to an s3 bucket configured for static website hosting.

I use next's `build` and `export` commands to generate the `out/` directory and then copy that into my s3 bucket

The bucket then contains some files, for simplicity lets say there's just `index.html` and `about.html`

The problem is when a user hits `index.html` via `www.website.com` then navigates to `www.website.com/about` everything works, but reloading `www.website.com/about` fails of course.

`www.website.com/about.html` finds the correct asset to render the site however

Is there a way to export a static next.js app, host on s3, and have requests to `/about` proxy `/about.html` ?

As always, thanks for looking, and thanks even more for participating.

Answer (score 13):

On your `next.config.js` file at the root of the project.

```javascript
module.exports = {
    trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Now you can create your pages (e.g. `about.jsx`) inside the `pages` directory and Next will create a folder with the file name with an `index.html` file inside of it when you run the `export` command.

Give it a try, worked fine here.

Comment: This works but results in an ugly final / on all routes

Comment: Thank you for explaining that it creates a directory! This solved my problem. Other people can cry about the trailing slash but idc 

Answer (score 7):

The best solution I've arrived at so far, inspired by this gist: 
https://gist.github.com/rbalicki2/30e8ee5fb5bc2018923a06c5ea5e3ea5

Basically when deploying the build to the s3 bucket, you can simply rename the `.html` files to have no `.html` suffix, ex: `www.bucket.com/about.html` -> `www.bucket.com/about` and now both SSR & CSR routing work as expected.

The resulting files have `Content-Type: text/html` despite not having the suffix, I don't know if this is problematic or not.

Comment: This definitely solves the problem but is totally hacky, is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: @James - Did you find any other workaround for this? I am not using S3 but also experiencing this issue.

Comment: @wind_kind I haven't touched this in quite a while - out of curiosity where are you hosting and having the same problem?

Comment: @James - I'm hosting with godaddy but I fixed this by changing some htaccess rewrite rules with the help from you posts above. I added this `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]` - since then I no longer have this issue.

Comment: @wind_kind using `.htaccess` redirect is the way to go, s3 is not a webserver and does not have a comparable solution

Comment: @James I´m trying this solution but every time that i run a reload the file is downloaded.
does the same happen to you?

Comment: @koutatcruzado it's hard to say without seeing what you're doing in s3 but you probably need to set `content-type: text/html` on your file.

Comment: Worked for me. Only issue I have is that next.js seems to acting weird with my rewrites on S3, but works fine locally. Cheers!

Comment: I'm using gitlab ci/cd. So build and export are on the docker image and output files have .html extension. How can i achive this status?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how [Guy Hudash](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/hosting-a-next-js-app-with-routing-on-aws-s3-fb1aa8adf120) did it:

Assuming you already have a react.js website hosted on s3, you need to first change the S3 **Routing Rules** in **`S3 bucket -> Properties -> Static website hosting -> Redirection`** rules.

The new s3 console changes the routing rules format to JSON, so you’ll need to add this (**don’t forget to replace myhost.com**):

```
[
  {
    "Condition": {
      "HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals": "404"
    },
    "Redirect": {
      "HostName": "myhost.com",
      "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "#!/"
    }
  },
  {
    "Condition": {
      "HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals": "403"
    },
    "Redirect": {
      "HostName": "myhost.com",
      "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "#!/"
    }
  }
]
```

These rules add `#!/` as the prefix to the URL in the case of a `403` or `404` error. This solves the react-router issue and now it will load the right page.

Now we would like to remove this prefix from the url for a cleaner solution. You’ll need to edit you **`_app.js`** and add:

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const path = (/#!(\/.*)$/.exec(router.asPath) || [])[1];
  if (path) {
    router.replace(path);
  }

  return (
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  );
};
export default MyApp;
```

You may refer to the [blog-post](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/hosting-a-next-js-app-with-routing-on-aws-s3-fb1aa8adf120) itself... or if you are using any other routing solution than NextJS for you application, or looking for more detailed explanation then look at: [Mark Biek blog](https://via.studio/journal/hosting-a-reactjs-app-with-routing-on-aws-s3)

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L] 
worked fine (y)

Comment: Where would you put this rewrite rule?

Comment: It's Apache config; but you can use it on S3 (I think); see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html

Comment: Does anyone have a json or xml example of this configuration and working, because it sounds ideal but as far as I can see it isn't relevant to s3.