# How to deploy NextJS application to Linux Server (CentOS 7) - VPS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, deployment, next.js

I've got a question regarding building applications. I'm using simple VPS with node.js support. Now I do not know how to build my next.js application to production.

I want to deploy my application as static files.

I thought that I should use `next build && next export` then copy out dir to the server but during this process, I faced some issues - when I change route - everything is okay, but if I refresh the page - the page is not found because the server is looking for this file in directories. So how can I deploy my nextjs application in production mode with VPS server and static files?

I tried one thing which is not working fine probably or I did something wrong.
I added nodejs express server with

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const app = next({dev});
const router = express.Router();
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare()
    .then(() => {

        const server = express();

        server.get('*', (req, res) => {
            return handle(req, res);
        });

        server.listen(3000, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
        });
    });
```

and start server with forever library `NODE_ENV=production node server.js` and it's working fine, but seems this is working in a wrong way - seems it's normal server like in dev mode - so it shouldn't be like that. (I see thunder icon on the right-bottom corner and I see all files which are same as in dev mode).

I want to deploy everything as static files.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you `build` and `export` you need to serve those files somehow. The reason the Express server works is because you are starting a HTTP server to serve the files.

So you need to serve those files either by using a static hosting provider (i.e. [Vercel](https://vercel.com) or Amazon S3). Otherwise you should start a server on your linux machine using something like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) to serve it at a port, similar to your Express server serving it as localhost:3000 which is then exposed on your VPS.

Comment: Okay got it :) But in this case that wouldn't be static pages, right? All I want is use static pages to improve SEO.
If I will use this library, which command should I use to serve it properly without development mode?

Comment: I followed this tutorial to do everything properly and host static HTML by Amazon S3 ([link]https://medium.com/@kyle.galbraith/how-to-host-a-website-on-s3-without-getting-lost-in-the-sea-e2b82aa6cd38[/link]) but unfortunately when I'm going to some page and refresh it - still i got same issue - the file is not found.

Comment: It appears from this issue another person ran into this problem as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438566/next-js-export-static-s3-routing-fails-on-page-reload

I don't use S3 with Next so sorry i'm not any further help.

Comment: I got an issue. The issue was with config and out dir doesn't have proper files... Strange thing and really thank you for your help and time!

Comment: @james do you know if a vps set up for nodejs would work with nextjs? I built a simple nextjs project with a headless cms and I want to set up a vps (hostinger) for the app. Thks!